# Use of article "the"

Tags: word-usage, definite-article

Do we have to use the article "the" in the following example: Coordinator in (the) Director's Office, Department of Legal Affairs?

Answer (score 2):

In that case, "the" is necessary if the context is not ambiguous about the director (i.e. there is no ambiguity about which director is mentioned).

**Example**: "I have been working for three years at StackOverflow as a coordinator in **the** Director's Office"

On the contrary, if the director is just one among thousands, you have to write "a director".

**Example**: "I have been working for three years as a coordinator in **a** Director's Office"

If you need further explanations, [check here](https://www.vivquarry.com/wkshts/articles.html) for a summary of this rule.

Comment: The job position is needed to be put on a business card, so I have to keep it as simple as possible. The job position is Coordinator in the office of the Director of 
 the Department of Legal Affairs and the title should be kept as short as possible.

Comment: Then, if the company name is written on the card or identified by a logo or sth, you should put a "the".

Comment: Are you the only co-ordinator in that office or are there several?

Comment: In the rule summary you linked, there are examples like "*Cat's like milk*" which seem incorrect. Otherwise this page is helpful.